Setting Up Properties in a JAR Executable
I have made a program that uses multiple classes that do various tasks. Every class however will need to reference the same file path every run. So, in my jar executable I have a properties file that has 2 properties, filePath and installStatus. When I first run the program it tests installStatus and if thats "false" then the user is prompted to select a location where certain files and folders are created. My default values in my jar config.properties is 'FileLocation=null' and 'Install=false'. This properties file (in eclipse) is located in the same package as my classes for ease of access. When I access config to test the install status (to ensure I've ran the program once and made the necessary files) I get no errors and the program proceeds to install properly. My code for the execution to find these properties is as below:
    prop.load(installationClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        
        // If the "Install" property is false then that means this program
        // is being run for the first time to we go through the installation
        // process and if it isn't, move to the next class
        if(prop.getProperty("Install").equals("false")) {
            myObj.installLocation();
        } else {
            FileNotFoundGUI fnfGUI = new FileNotFoundGUI();
            fnfGUI.mainMethod();
        }

At the end of the execution of this class, I wish to update my properties to the filePath the user chose and install to true. I do that as shown below:
prop.setProperty("Install", "true");
filePath = filePath + "\\Tracking Program\\Text Files";
prop.setProperty("FileLocation", filePath);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("config.properties");
prop.store(fw, null);

However, this creates a new config.properties file in the same file location as my jar file which I need a filePath to navigate to and open. And to get that filePath in the other classes, I must access the properties file to retrieve which of course they don't know where it is. Is there a way I can write to this config.properties file thats packed within my jar file?
I have unpacked my jar file to ensure my config.properties file is in there, which it is and it has my original additions to it. Those additions just will not update as it makes that new properties file. I have tried various ways to access this properties file as well as trying to access within the jar file which as of yet hasn't worked. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
TLDR: I want to access, read from, and write to a properties file that is stored within an executable jar file.

Resources are read-only. You can't write to your property file. Save the data in a .yourapp.conf file off user.home

Or whatever directory you want. The insides of a jar are not a directory.

You would be better to use Reader and Writer for properties as they give you more flexibility, plus the alternative confines you to 'ascii', which can have suprising and odd side effects. Also try-with-resources is your friend. When you load Properties, the stream does not get closed. This should be tightened more as the directory might be there but someone might have deleted the file.
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;

public class PropertiesTest {
    public static final String CONFIG_FILE = "config.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Creating first property value to ensure they work seperately
        // then making the directory that I wish to read from later
        // System.getProperty("user.home") leads to C:\Users\YourUser
        // so I am creating a file "Tracking Program" in C:\Users\YourUser
        Properties propertiesWrite = new Properties();
        // File theDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Tracking
        // Program");
        Path configDir = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Tracking Program");
        boolean firstRun = true;
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(configDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            firstRun = false;
        }

        if (firstRun) {
            // Creating two values (FileLocation and Install) and giving them
            // values (null and false)
            propertiesWrite.setProperty("FileLocation", "null");
            propertiesWrite.setProperty("Install", "false");

            // This creates the config.properties file at the given destination
            // and will also allow us to write to it
            try (Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(configDir.resolve(CONFIG_FILE))) {
                // Storing the values we just created at fileOutputStream
                // and not leaving any comments within the file
                propertiesWrite.store(out, null);
            }
        }

        // Creating a new properties value to ensure no confusion
        // between the usage of the properties variables
        Properties propertiesRead = new Properties();

        // Creating a file reader that will allow us to read
        // from our properties file

        try (Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader(configDir.resolve(CONFIG_FILE))) {
            // Loading the properties file so that we can actually
            // retrieve data from it
            propertiesRead.load(in);
        }
        // Printing out one of the values to ensure we access the correct
        // file and that it was properly written to (Prints "false")
        System.out.println(propertiesRead.getProperty("Install"));
    }
}


Thankyou all again for your invaluable help. Here is the solution I have come up with in case others wish to do the same as I.
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class PropertiesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        
        // Creating first property value to ensure they work seperately
        // then making the directory that I wish to read from later
        // System.getProperty("user.home") leads to C:\Users\YourUser
        // so I am creating a file "Tracking Program" in C:\Users\YourUser
        Properties propertiesWrite = new Properties(); 
        File theDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Tracking Program");
        theDir.mkdir();

        // This creates the config.properties file at the given destination
        // and will also allow us to write to it
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream  = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Tracking Program\\config.properties"); 
  
        // Creating two values (FileLocation and Install) and giving them
        // values (null and false)
        propertiesWrite.setProperty("FileLocation", "null"); 
        propertiesWrite.setProperty("Install", "false"); 
  
        // Storing the values we just created at fileOutputStream
        // and not leaving any comments within the file
        propertiesWrite.store(fileOutputStream,null); 
        
        // Closing fileOutputStream to avoid any memory leaks
        fileOutputStream.close(); 
        
        // Creating a new properties value to ensure no confusion
        // between the usage of the properties variables
        Properties propertiesRead = new Properties();
        
        // Creating a file reader that will allow us to read
        // from our properties file
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Tracking Program\\config.properties");
        
        // Loading the properties file so that we can actually 
        // retrieve data from it
        propertiesRead.load(fr);
        
        // Printing out one of the values to ensure we access the correct
        // file and that it was properly written to (Prints "false")
        System.out.println(propertiesRead.getProperty("Install"));
    }
}


Why do you need a property "Install"? If not installed, there wouldn't be a local properties file so check if that file exists and if missing install and  write a valid file afterwards.

I have done just that now that everything works, but it doesn't change how the answer works as people can change variables to be whatever they wish.

@g00se I do have another class that makes sure that it has all the necessary files in the directory as a just-in-case. Thankfully I have not ran into this ascii issue as I am purely using strings within these files I'm reading from. Nonetheless, a great addition :)
